# How to place a RelativeLayout front other layout Android

Tags: android, authentication, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a question about layout android.
This is layout image that i want to make it. Like this:

This is image exmaple:

[image]

Here my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/first_screen_bg"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/linerTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="55"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/linerBottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:background="@color/grey" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@id/linerMidle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                android:background="@color/black" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@id/linerFlag"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_flag" >
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout><RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But it not running.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What you want to do be specific?

Comment: will you please tell what you really want to do? please ellaborate your requirement. None of them can understand anything from this question. so please explain what you really want to do. Then only we can help you.

Comment: I try to make layout it look like picture above. The red flag center right of line between linerTop and linerBottom.

Answer (score 0):

change yout layout.xml to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/first_screen_bg"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/linerTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="55"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/linerBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:background="@color/grey" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/linerMidle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:background="@color/black" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/linerFlag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_flag" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It not running. @id/linerFlag behide  @id/linerTop